# How to set SDK release when using Bitbucket repository integration

Tags: bitbucket, sentry

I have installed Bitbucket integration on sentry and used the Bitbucket pipeline to automatically notify and associate releases with commits as described [here](https://bitbucket.org/sentryio/sentry-new-release/src/master/)

I have also set up source maps to be uploaded as seen below:

```
sentry-cli releases files $BITBUCKET_COMMIT upload-sourcemaps build
```

The Bitbucket pipeline and the source map upload both use the `$BITBUCKET_COMMIT` as the identifier.

I am trying to figure out how to configure the SDK release to use this variable as my current set up is below:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV.toString().toLowerCase() === 'production') {
    Sentry.init({
        dsn: process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN,
    });
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution on this yet?

Comment: Yhup anwered below now

Comment: thank you very much. we ended up with a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do this. The BITBUCKET_COMMIT is an environment variable available in the bitbucket pipeline during build so I made this available to my docker container by passing it as an argument in the Docker build step.

```
docker build --build-arg release=$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
```

I could then make the passed variable available to my React build command through the DockerFile

```
//DockerFile
ENV BITBUCKET_COMMIT=$release
```

Then within my package.json I set the variable during build

```
"build": "REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN=$BITBUCKET_COMMIT"
```